# Too many subjective questions lately

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I realize as a beta, any question is often seen as a good question. But I fear that *too many* overly subjective questions will just do far more harm than good.

When new users see that these types of question are accepted and open (and all at the top of the list on the front page):

[Helping a client get what they deserve from their ISP](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/helping-a-client-get-what-they-deserve-from-their-isp)

[Gone into deep hole with client. What next?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/gone-into-deep-hole-with-client-what-next)

[Buying a domain for your client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/buying-a-domain-for-your-client)

[How to deal with a stubborn user that constantly makes mistakes, but refuses to accept it's their fault](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/how-to-deal-with-a-stubborn-user-that-constantly-makes-mistakes-but-refuses-to)

["Work faster and I'll pay you higher,"?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/work-faster-and-ill-pay-you-higher)

[What freelancing jobs I can start without knowledge about it?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/what-freelancing-jobs-i-can-start-without-knowledge-about-it)

They feel justified in posting their own, broad, opinion-based, vague, subjective question.

Since this is a beta site, there doesn't appear to be a large pool of users capable of voting to close questions. So, moderators *may* need to be a tad more aggressive in some cases and close questions a bit faster.

I'm not implying that *my opinion* of what is openly vague is always accurate. I merely see 3 down votes on something, and only 1 close vote. In many cases, if these types of questions are down voted I can only assume it's because they are poor questions (which I agree with). After all it's not possible to have a "lack of effort" based on the context of the questions.

Anyway.... just a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking a question.  My opinion on the subject: the community is slow. very slow. But I do agree with the analysis that the questions are questionable.  Bad questions or no questions. Perhaps letting through some questionable questions till the community is strong?  Not sure.  That would take away from the integrity of the site.